# Update Android ListView in Widget

Tags: android, listview, service, widget

I have a problem with my App-Widget when i try to update the content.

The widget looks like this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEGLv.jpg

The Widget consists of a Header (Buttons + TextViews) and a ListView.
If the User press a Button the ListView shows the content of the next day and everything works fine. But the problem is, if i try to update the widget from my app or the automatically timeperiod the ListView doenst update.

Here the my Code.

AppWidgetProvider:

```
public class StudyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider{

private static String BUTTON_BACK = "BUTTON_BACK";
private static String BUTTON_FORWARD = "BUTTON_FORWARD";

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {  
    context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    if(WidgetViewsFactory.currentDate == null){
        WidgetViewsFactory.currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    }

    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(action != null){
        if(action.equals(BUTTON_BACK)){
            WidgetViewsFactory.currentDate.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
        }
        if(action.equals(BUTTON_FORWARD)){
            WidgetViewsFactory.currentDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
    }

    context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));
}   
 }
```

The UpdateService which handles the update of the Widget.

```
    @Override
@Deprecated
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Update-Service started");

    RemoteViews widget = buildUpdate(this);
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(this, StudyWidgetProvider.class);
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);

    manager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(manager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget), R.id.words);
    manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, widget);

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "The Content!");
    if(widgetObjects == null){
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "WidgetObjects sind NULL");
    } else {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "WidgetObjects sind NICHT-NULL");

        for(int i=0; i<widgetObjects.size(); i++){
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "--- " + widgetObjects.get(i).getName());
        }
    }

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Update-Service ended");
}


public RemoteViews buildUpdate(Context context){
    RemoteViews retVal = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

    if(WidgetViewsFactory.currentDate == null){
        WidgetViewsFactory.currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    }

    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), StudyWidgetProvider.class.getName());
    int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);

    loadSDCardContent(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    //Setzen des Widget-UIs
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

    retVal.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.words, intent);

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    retVal.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_day, dateFormater.format(WidgetViewsFactory.currentDate.getTime()));
    dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    retVal.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_date, dateFormater.format(WidgetViewsFactory.currentDate.getTime()));

    //Button-Actions
    Intent backIntent = new Intent(context, StudyWidgetProvider.class);
    backIntent.setAction(BUTTON_BACK);
    Intent forwardIntent = new Intent(context, StudyWidgetProvider.class);
    forwardIntent.setAction(BUTTON_FORWARD);
    PendingIntent backPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, backIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent forwardPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, forwardIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    retVal.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_but_back, backPendingIntent);
    retVal.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_but_forward, forwardPendingIntent);

    Intent clickIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetActivity.class);
    PendingIntent clickPI=PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    retVal.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.words, clickPI);

    return retVal;
}
```

And heres how i update the widget from my app:

```
public RemoteViews buildUpdate(Context context){
    RemoteViews retVal = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

    if(WidgetViewsFactory.currentDate == null){
        WidgetViewsFactory.currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    }

    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), StudyWidgetProvider.class.getName());
    int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);

    loadSDCardContent(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    //Setzen des Widget-UIs
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

    retVal.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.words, intent);

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    retVal.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_day, dateFormater.format(WidgetViewsFactory.currentDate.getTime()));
    dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    retVal.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_date, dateFormater.format(WidgetViewsFactory.currentDate.getTime()));

    //Button-Actions
    Intent backIntent = new Intent(context, StudyWidgetProvider.class);
    backIntent.setAction(BUTTON_BACK);
    Intent forwardIntent = new Intent(context, StudyWidgetProvider.class);
    forwardIntent.setAction(BUTTON_FORWARD);
    PendingIntent backPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, backIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent forwardPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, forwardIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    retVal.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_but_back, backPendingIntent);
    retVal.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_but_forward, forwardPendingIntent);

    Intent clickIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetActivity.class);
    PendingIntent clickPI=PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    retVal.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.words, clickPI);

    return retVal;
}
```

The strange thing is when i hit the button of the widget, everythings work as i wish. The onDatasetChanged-method of my listview gets called and the content is changing, but if i try this from my app nothing happens

I hope someone of you have an idea why this isnt working. 
Im stuck on this for now 2 days and i have no clue...

Thanks for helping!

**EDIT**
Ive found out that this isnt working on my device (htc with miui v4) but on the emulator.

**EDIT 2**
I installed Android 4 (with Sense 4) on my device, and after that it worked too. It looks like MIUI was the problem.

Comment: Do you think user1392070 is a good name choice?

Comment: Issue a stickyBroadcast to update your widget.

Comment: Use broadcasts to communicate with the widget instead of all this code.  Don't call onUpdate directly like this.

Comment: I have tried to update it with a BroadcastReceiver but i get the same result.

Comment: Same problem... was hoping someone would have a solution.

Comment: Any solution for this? You said that "The onDatasetChanged-method of my listview gets called and the content is changing", but what code did you put in onDataSetChanged to update the contents of the list? Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to necro this question because I had the same issue and found a solution.

```
              manager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged
```

This sends a call to onDataSetChanged() in your RemoteViewsFactory. Add a call to build your Views in that method. This solved all my problems.

Comment: I have the same problem please refer my link and give me solution...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524974/listivew-widget-not-updating-automatically

Comment: where should `manager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged` be putted?

Answer (score 1):

Communicate with the Widget via Broadcasts only. Dont call it directly like this.  Use stickyBroadcasts if needed.

Comment: I have tried to update it with a BroadcastReceiver but i get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
 @Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    for (int widgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews mView = initViews(context, appWidgetManager, widgetId);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, mView);
    }

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}



@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private RemoteViews initViews(Context context,
                              AppWidgetManager widgetManager, int widgetId) {

    RemoteViews mView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget_layout);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);

    intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
    mView.setRemoteAdapter(widgetId, R.id.widgetCollectionList, intent);

    return mView;
}
```